# Using ternary statement in a lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, lambda, syntax

I've been trying to round a vector of a DataFrame using a lambda function. In my vector I also have string values, so I tried this code:

```py
dff.apply(lambda x: round(x, 2) if (isinstance(x,float)))
```

But it raises a SyntaxError.

Comment: ternary expression needs an `else`, Maybe you need `lambda x: round(x, 2) if (isinstance(x,float)) else x`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Seems like there should be a canonical dupe for this common error.

Comment: probably but I'm not too familiar with pandas. Adding `else x` may be too late when maybe the data type should be filtered upstream. Re-tagging

Comment: It's not a lambda function; it's just a function. Lambda *expressions* are one way to define a function in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. tenary if-else missing the else statement. Like answered by user17242583.
2. `dff.apply` digest column by column, thus the `isinstance(x,float)` will not work for rounding. Use the vectorized `numpy.round` instead.

```
dff.apply( lambda x: np.round(x,2))
```

Comment: "*Use the vectorized numpy.round instead*" most sensible choice indeed,  and if a single value function is really required, use [Series.map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map) or [DataFrame.map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.map.html#pandas-dataframe-map).

Answer (score 1):

Ternary statement in Python require `else` after the condition.

```py
dff.apply(lambda x: round(x, 2) if (isinstance(x,float)) else x)
```